# What parameters have to be passed through mysqli_num_rows?

Tags: php, mysqli, phpmyadmin

I'm working on a small project in PHP. I'm trying to get numbers corresponding with categories in my database to display, but I keep getting the same error multiple times on the display page:

> Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs(A)Book 2.0\Bootstrap\content_function.php on line 34

Here is what the code looks like that the error is targeting:

```
function getnumtopics($cat_id, $subcat_id){
include ('../db.php');
$select = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT category_id, subcategory_id FROM topics WHERE".$cat_id." = category_id
                    AND ".$subcat_id." = subcategory_id");

return mysqli_num_rows($select);
```

}

Line 34 is the return statement. It seems like a problem with my syntax?

Comment: It's not a good idea to include that connection (and most likely open a new connection) each time you run that query. Pass the connection as an argument instead

Comment: I have the connection passed as an argument in the db.php file. It's not a good idea to include the file in each function? (I'm pretty new to PHP)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
function getnumtopics($cat_id, $subcat_id){
include ('../db.php');
$select = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT category_id, subcategory_id FROM topics WHERE ".$cat_id." = category_id
                    AND ".$subcat_id." = subcategory_id");
$get = mysqli_num_rows($select);

return $get;
```

Comment: Why should anyone "try this", a good answer always includes an explanation and some text, not just a codedump

Comment: @CaptainAmerica16 Most Welcome :) Do not forget to accept my answer.

Comment: I see what you mean, but at least now in the future I have this technique to rely on should I come across this error again.

Comment: @Qirel i will take care of this :)

Answer (score 3):

You should check the result (that is `$select(result)`) of `mysqli_query` before passing it to `mysqli_num_rows`, see the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/20420281)

Comment: **mysqli_query** has mixed return types. So you have to split your command into two independant ones to create a mysqli_result variable.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is here:

```
"SELECT category_id, subcategory_id FROM topics WHERE".$cat_id." = category_id AND ".$subcat_id." = subcategory_id"
```

There are two issues in your query, first you forget to add and space after `WHERE` and second while comparing with the string, you have to concatenate it with single quotes like:

```
"SELECT category_id, subcategory_id FROM topics WHERE ".$cat_id." = 'category_id' AND ".$subcat_id." = 'subcategory_id'";
```

try the above query.

Comment: Now I'm just getting this: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ',' or ')' in C:\xampp\htdocs\(A)Book 2.0\Bootstrap\content_function.php on line 32

Comment: I sorted it out with a separate answer. Thank you for your help.